# Seeking a way to operate a Laundry Dryer when I'm not using my Kitchen Stove/Oven

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I want to use a Clothes Dryer in my Apartment, but it requires a 240 volt plug.  The only place that has such a plug is the Kitchen Stove/Oven.  Is there a splitter available (or could I make one) so I can roll the Dryer into the Kitchen and use the Dryer in the Evening when I am not using the Stove/Oven without having to pull the stove out and unplug it, to plug in the Dryer?  Then I could put the 220 volt plug socket on the wall above the Stove for easy access to plug in the Dryer?

Comment: do you own the apartment or do you rent/lease?

Comment: Does your apartment not have a dryer hookup at all, or is the existing dryer hookup only provisioned for gas dryers? Is your dryer a *condensing* type with its own reservoir/drain line, or does it have a conventional dryer vent duct coming out of it?

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea.  Those large NEMA 10-50 connectors are *not  made for frequent use*. Because of the very high insertion force, they are actually much more fragile than you would assume.

Also, you are almost certainly dealing with old 3-prong NEMA 10 ungrounded connectors.  Dryers or stoves connect via an exception in the electrical code, in which they are allowed to **bootleg ground**, tying the machine chassis to the neutral wire.  This is dangerous because if the neutral wire ever breaks, it will electrify the machine's chassis!   The logic is "these connectors are unlikely to fail **because they are rarely unplugged**“.

*See a problem?*

An additional problem is that dryers are made to be matched with 30A breakers, not 40A or 50A.